# How to re-order array of bytes by integer size then reverse back?

Tags: c#, math, encoding, compression, encode

Is it possible to re-order an array of 8-bit bytes by their integer size (high to low or vice versa) while still being able to retrieve the original byte locations back? I'm looking to do this in the least amount of bytes possible.

ie: int[] array = { 10, 250, 50, 17, 12, 140, 30, 221 };

I would like to have the array expressed in ascending or descending order as a byte array while still being able to return it back to normal

The new byte array will be written to a file. Therefore the only information available to decode is the new byte array.

Appreciate the help, thank you!

Comment: @jannagy02 but how would I go about returning it back to its original state if all I have now is the converted byte array?

Comment: var newArray = array.OrderBy(x => x); the variable "array" will have the original order.

Comment: @jannagy02 updated the question

Comment: like a radix sort? how many elements?

Comment: There is no limit on the number of elements. For this example using 8 but it could just as easily be 800

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb308959.aspx)

```
var sortedArray = array.OrderBy(x => x);
var sortedArrayDesc = array.OrderByDescending(x => x);
```

Both `sortedArray` and `sortedArrayDesc` are [IEnumerable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable(v=vs.110).aspx), they won't be evaluated until you use them, and they are enumerators over your collection